# How to migrate existing permissions to new domain

Tags: facebook, dns

I am not a developer myself, but conceptually our App has run into an issue.

We have several hundred installs of our App with "Allow" permissions granted to our current domain, which serves the functions of the App... but we are now moving our webservice and App to a new domain for reasons of better marketability (the new domain name is better).

Since we will be offering the exact same service, just under a different name, we would like to migrate the service of the App without having every end-user re-register and "Allow" our App, OR be able to rename the App on the Facebook end (essentially "skinning" or whitelabelling it under the new name).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **App Domain** in the application settings section in http://facebook.com/developers - Keep the old domain and add the new domain as well(just type the domain name, hit enter and then click on save button)

The application will then start working on your new domain without any code change :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Our app creates updates that appear as posts on the users' Wall.  When these are created, it says "Friday at 11:49am via Our-Old-Site.com".  

We wish for even the users who signed up before the change to have their Wall update with "Friday at 11:49am via Our-NEW-Site.com" ... will this be possible in the solution you offered?

Comment: @ShaunNilsson can't that just changed by changing the *App Display Name*?